# I am reading and writing in/to files in assembly but my program is crashing

Tags: assembly, masm

I need to read 8 byte at a time from a .txt file. For now, I just want to display that block to a destination .txt file. The problem is that my program is crashing and I cannot figure out at which point. I chose to read one byte at a time until I have 8 and then repeat until the end of the file. I use masm. Here is the code:

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
includelib msvcrt.lib
extern printf: proc
extern scanf: proc
extern fscanf: proc
extern fprintf: proc
extern fopen: proc
extern fclose: proc
extern exit: proc

;
public start

;data section
.data
  scanf_format db "%d",0
  printf_format db "%c",0

  ascii db 0 
  type_read db "r",0
  type_write db "w", 0
  destination db "destinatie.txt",0
  fscanf_format db "%c",0 
  fprintf_format db "%c",0
  start_msg db "The path to the source file :",0
  source dd 0 
  source_format db "%s", 0
  pointer_source dd 0
  pointer_destination dd 0

  buffer db 8 dup(0)
  buffer_l equ 7

  step_nr dd 0
  step dd 0
  end_of_file dd 0
;the code section
.code

start:
    xor eax,eax
    ; The path to the source file
    push offset start_msg
    add esp,4
    ; read the source file name
    push  offset source
    push offset source_format
    call scanf
    add esp,8
    ; open source file
    push offset type_read
    push offset source
    call fopen
    add esp,8
    mov pointer_source,eax 


    ; create the destination file 
    push offset type_write
    push offset destination
    call fopen
    mov pointer_destination,eax 
    add esp,8



read_file: 
       lea esi,buffer
       mov step,esi
       mov esi,step
       xor edi,edi
       mov edi,esi
       add edi,7
       dec esi
       for_0_7:
          push offset ascii
          push offset fscanf_format
          push pointer_source
          call fscanf
          add esp,12
          mov end_of_file,eax
          cmp end_of_file,0ffffffffH
          je write_file    
          xor ebx,ebx
          mov bl,ascii
          inc esi
          mov [esi],ebx
          cmp esi,edi
          jb for_0_7

       ;display the blocks
        mov end_of_file,eax 
        mov step,esi
        inc step   
        xor edi,edi
        xor esi,esi
        lea ESI, buffer
        mov ecx,8
        dec esi

       write_file:
         inc esi
         xor edx,edx
         mov dl,[esi]
         ;push [esi]
         push edx
         push offset fprintf_format
         push pointer_destination
         call fprintf
         add esp,12
         cmp [esi],ecx
         jne write_file
       cmp end_of_file,0ffffffffH
       jne read_file
jmp next


final :
         push 0
         call exit

next: push pointer_source
          call fclose
          add esp,4
          push pointer_destination
          call fclose
          add esp,4
          jmp final


end start
```

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in a debugger? Visual Studio has a debugger, but if you don't have that you might consider [Ollydbg](http://www.ollydbg.de/). Being able to debug your own code and watch what is going on will be a very handy skill.

Comment: I tried using Ollydbg. It seems like my program doesn't even get to display the start message. I have no clue what I am doing wrong. I am new to assembly.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't print the start message because the call to`printf` is missing between `push offset start_msg` and `add esp,4`?

Comment: Yes, I mistakenly deleted it and did not notice. It does get the first 8 byte segment but it seems that it stops working at `mov dl,[esi]`

Comment: how do you build this code with masm?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are asking, but I use notepad++ and some plug-ins to build the asm code.

Comment: I see at least a couple of potential problems. For example, you provide `fscanf` with a pointer to a single byte (`ascii`) while using the `%d` specifier, but `%d` without any length sub-specifier assumes an `int*` (i.e. a pointer to a dword). Also, when reading from the file you're doing `mov [esi],ebx` even though the elements in the buffer are supposed to be one byte each. So e.g. when you're at `buffer+6` you'll be writing to `[buffer+6..buffer+9]`, i.e. outside the bounds of `buffer`. You've also got some useless instructions in there, like `mov esi,step` directly after `mov step,esi`.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I've used a different approach after all, but I will be trying to fix this based on your suggestions.  Thanks again.